# Get Sum of All the Month

Tags: php

```
<?php
$log = array (
  array('AName'=>'Assessment','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09'),
  array('AName'=>'Assessment','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09'),
  array('AName'=>'Assessment','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09'),
  array('AName'=>'Assessment','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'08'),
  array('AName'=>'Assessment','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'07'),
  array('AName'=>'Linkage Programs','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09'),
  array('AName'=>'Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'08'),
  array('AName'=>'Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09'),
  array('AName'=>'Recovery Homes','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'08'),
  array('AName'=>'Recovery Homes','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'08'),
  array('AName'=>'Recovery Homes','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09')
);
$data = array();
foreach($log as $event)
{
    if(isset($event['Month']))
    {
        $data[$event['Month']][$event['AName']] = (!isset($data[$event['Month']][$event['AName']])) ? 1 : $data[$event['Month']][$event['AName']] + 1;
    }
}
var_dump($data);
$totalArray = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $keys => $values) 
  {
        echo $key.'-->'.$keys.'-->'.$values.'<br>';
  }  
}
?>
```

Here is my code and I have grouped the AName by month, individually 
I am getting the count of AName by month , now i want to get sum of AName of all months like if "Assessment" has count 3 in november, count 2 in october , then total sum of "Assessment" should be 5 (sum of AName by all months). Kindly help

Comment: Does the data come from mysql? If so you could/should be doing the operation in mysql instead of php

Comment: Of course data is coming from mysql but we have requirement to do in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this line of code:

```
$data2[$event['AName']] = isset($data2[$event['AName']]) ? $data2[$event['AName']] +1 : 1;
```

after

```
$data[$event['Month']][$event['AName']] = (!isset($data[$event['Month']][$event['AName']])) ? 1 : $data[$event['Month']][$event['AName']] + 1;
```

[Check here for output](https://3v4l.org/Nu8El)

**O/P be like**

```
Array ( 
       [Assessment] => 5 
       [Linkage Programs] => 1 
       [Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs] => 2 
       [Recovery Homes] => 3 
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .You saved my day

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want

**Your updated code i have updated your code.**

```
<?php 
    $log = array (
      array('AName'=>'Assessment','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09'),
      array('AName'=>'Assessment','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09'),
      array('AName'=>'Assessment','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09'),
      array('AName'=>'Assessment','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'08'),
      array('AName'=>'Assessment','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'07'),
      array('AName'=>'Linkage Programs','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09'),
      array('AName'=>'Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'08'),
      array('AName'=>'Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09'),
      array('AName'=>'Recovery Homes','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'08'),
      array('AName'=>'Recovery Homes','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'08'),
      array('AName'=>'Recovery Homes','Year'=>'2018','Month'=>'09')
    );
    echo "<pre>";
    $data = array();
    foreach($log as $event)
    {
        if(isset($event['Month']))
        {
            $data[$event['Month']][$event['AName']] = (!isset($data[$event['Month']][$event['AName']])) ? 1 : $data[$event['Month']][$event['AName']] + 1;
        }
    }
    print_r($data);
    $totalArray = array();
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        foreach ($value as $keys => $values) 
      {
            echo $key.'-->'.$keys.'-->'.$values.'<br>';
              if($keys=='Assessment'){
                  $sumAssessment[] = $values;
                 }else if($keys=='Linkage Programs'){
                            $sumLinkage[] = $values;
                 }else if($keys=="Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs"){
                              $sumHousing[] = $values;
                            }else if($keys=='Recovery Homes'){
                              $sumRecovery[] = $values;
                            }
      }  
    }
    echo "Total Assessment=>".array_sum($sumAssessment).'<br>';
    echo "Total Linkage Programs=>".array_sum($sumLinkage).'<br>';
    echo "Total Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs=>".array_sum($sumHousing).'<br>';
    echo "Total Recovery Homes=>".array_sum($sumRecovery);
?>
```

**O/P**

```
  Array
(
    [09] => Array
        (
            [Assessment] => 3
            [Linkage Programs] => 1
            [Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs] => 1
            [Recovery Homes] => 1
        )

    [08] => Array
        (
            [Assessment] => 1
            [Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs] => 1
            [Recovery Homes] => 2
        )

    [07] => Array
        (
            [Assessment] => 1
        )

)
09-->Assessment-->3
09-->Linkage Programs-->1
09-->Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs-->1
09-->Recovery Homes-->1
08-->Assessment-->1
08-->Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs-->1
08-->Recovery Homes-->2
07-->Assessment-->1
Total Assessment=>5
Total Linkage Programs=>1
Total Housing Continuum of Care (CoC) Programs=>2
Total Recovery Homes=>3
```

Comment: I need for all the keys..it is static for only Assessment

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I got the answer